# Can you set different XCode Builder settings per project in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I'm brand new to Jenkins CI but liking it so far.  I have run into one serious issue though.  The XCode Builder settings are global settings.  I have different projects that require different versions of xcodebuild.  Is there a way to define those on a per project basis?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a way to do this using **xcrun** and **xcode-select**.

Run `man xcrun` and `man xcode-select` for details.

You may need the *xcode command line package* installed to see those commands.